# Create inputs N times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I am working on a form that initially asks for an amount of people:

```
<select name="amount" onClick="update()" id="amount">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

This then triggers the update function when any option is clicked which toggles the visibility of the next part of the form which is contained in a div called step2:

```
function update(){
    document.getElementById('step2').style.visibility='visible';
};
```

What I then want to do is create N inputs (N being how many people they selected)
So if they select 4 then 4 name inputs appear.
I have tried using this function:

```
function addinput(){
var wrapper         = $("#step2"); //Fields wrapper
var x = document.getElementById(amount).value;
for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="name" name="mytext[' + i + ']"/></div>');
    }
};
```

And then placing `addinput()` at the end of the update function.
However this does not work.
Is there any other way that will, or even, what am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Does not work because of a syntax error. Look at the console in your browser.

Comment: I presume the problem is on this line `var x = document.getElementById(amount).value;` The variable amount is not defined, you should have queried "amount" instead.

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("amount").value;`, also it is not necessary to call `jQuery()` again with `wrapper` as parameter within `for` loop.

Comment: @epascarello I have corrected the syntax error, however it still does not work.